# Tensorflow: preload multiple models

Tags: python, tensorflow

General question: How can you prevent that a model needs to be rebuild for each inference request?

I'm trying to develop a web-service that contains multiple trained models which can be used to request a prediction. Producing a results is now very time consuming because the model needs to be rebuild for each request.
The inferring itself only takes 30ms but importing the model takes more than a second.
I'm having difficulty splitting the importing and inference into two separate methods because of the needed session.

The solution i came up with is by using an `InteractiveSession` that is stored in a variable. On creation of the object the model gets loaded inside of this session that remains open. When a request is submitted this preloaded model is than used to generate the result.

Problem with this solution:
When creating multiple of this objects for different models, multiple Interactive sessions are open at the same time. Tensorflow generate the following warning:

```
Nesting violated for default stack of <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph'> objects
```

Any ideas how to manage multiple sessions and preload models?

```
class model_inference:
    def __init__(self, language_name, base_module="models"):
        """
        Load a network that can be used to perform inference.

        Args:

            lang_class (str): The name of an importable language class,
                returning an instance of `BaseLanguageModel`. This class
                should be importable from `base_module`.

            base_module (str):  The module from which to import the
                `language_name` class.

        Attributes:

            chkpt (str): The model checkpoint value.
            infer_model (g2p_tensor.nmt.model_helper.InferModel):
                The language infor_model instance.
        """

        language_instance = getattr(
            importlib.import_module(base_module), language_name
        )()
        self.ckpt = language_instance.checkpoint
        self.infer_model = language_instance.infer_model
        self.hparams = language_instance.hparams
        self.rebuild_infer_model()

    def rebuild_infer_model(self):
        """
        recreate infer model after changing hparams
        This is time consuming.
        :return:
        """
        self.session = tf.InteractiveSession(
            graph=self.infer_model.graph, config=utils.get_config_proto()
        )
        self.model = model_helper.load_model(
            self.infer_model.model, self.ckpt, self.session, "infer"
        )

    def infer_once(self, in_string):
        """
        Entrypoint of service, should not contain rebuilding of the model.
        """
        in_data = tokenize_input_string(in_string)

        self.session.run(
            self.infer_model.iterator.initializer,
            feed_dict={
                self.infer_model.src_placeholder: [in_data],
                self.infer_model.batch_size_placeholder: self.hparams.infer_batch_size,
            },
        )

        subword_option = self.hparams.subword_option
        beam_width = self.hparams.beam_width
        tgt_eos = self.hparams.eos
        num_translations_per_input = self.hparams.num_translations_per_input

        num_sentences = 0

        num_translations_per_input = max(
            min(num_translations_per_input, beam_width), 1
        )

        nmt_outputs, _ = self.model.decode(self.session)
        if beam_width == 0:
            nmt_outputs = np.expand_dims(nmt_outputs, 0)

        batch_size = nmt_outputs.shape[1]
        num_sentences += batch_size

        for sent_id in range(batch_size):
            for beam_id in range(num_translations_per_input):
                translation = nmt_utils.get_translation(
                    nmt_outputs[beam_id],
                    sent_id,
                    tgt_eos=tgt_eos,
                    subword_option=subword_option,
                )
        return untokenize_output_string(translation.decode("utf-8"))

    def __del__(self):
        self.session.close()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.session.close()
```

Comment: You can just create a `tf.Session` instead of a `tf.InteractiveSession`. `tf.InteractiveSession` is the same as `tf.Session`, only it sets itself as the default session. However, you are not using anything that relies on the default session (e.g. `eval()`), and even if you did you could use the `self.session.as_default()` context manager in your methods.

Comment: I did try that but it gives me a big ununderstandable error ending in:  `ValueError: Operation name: "init_all_tables"
op: "NoOp" is not an element of this graph. `

Comment: That seems a different issue. You should probably use `with self.infer_model.graph.as_default():` contexts in your methods when you create new operations, to ensure that these are created within the same graph as the inference model.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of jdehesa's comments i understood what went wrong.
When not specifying which graph needs to be used. Tensorflow makes a new instance of a graph and adds the operations to it. That's why just changing the `InteractiveSession` to a normal `Session` to not nest interactive sessions will throw a new error `ValueError: Operation name: "init_all_tables" op: "NoOp" is not an element of this graph.`

The use of a `InteractiveSession` worked because it sets the defined graph to be used as default in stead of creating a new instance. The problem with the `InteractiveSession` is that its very bad to leave multiple sessions open at the same time. Tensorflow will throw a warning.

The solution was the following:
When changing the `InteractiveSession` to a normal `Session` you need to explicitly define in which graph you want to reload the model with `model_helper.load_model`.
This can be done by defining a context: `with self.infer_model.graph.as_default():`

The eventual solution was the following:

```
def rebuild_infer_model(self):
    """
    recreate infer model after changing hparams
    This is time consuming.
    :return:
    """
    self.session = tf.Session(
        graph=self.infer_model.graph, config=utils.get_config_proto()
    )
    # added line:
    with self.infer_model.graph.as_default(): # the model should be loaded within the same graph as when infering!!
        model_helper.load_model(
            self.infer_model.model, self.ckpt, self.session, "infer"
        )

def infer_once(self, in_string):
    """
    Turn an orthographic transcription into a phonetic transcription
    The transcription is processed all at once
    Long transcriptions may result in incomplete phonetic output
    :param in_string: orthographic transcription
    :return: string of the phonetic representation
    """
    # added line:
    with self.infer_model.graph.as_default():
        in_data = tokenize_input_string(in_string)

        self.session.run(
            self.infer_model.iterator.initializer,
            feed_dict={
                self.infer_model.src_placeholder: [in_data],
                self.infer_model.batch_size_placeholder: self.hparams.infer_batch_size,
            },
        )

        subword_option = self.hparams.subword_option
        beam_width = self.hparams.beam_width
        tgt_eos = self.hparams.eos
        num_translations_per_input = self.hparams.num_translations_per_input

        num_sentences = 0

        num_translations_per_input = max(
            min(num_translations_per_input, beam_width), 1
        )

        nmt_outputs, _ = self.infer_model.model.decode(self.session)
        if beam_width == 0:
            nmt_outputs = np.expand_dims(nmt_outputs, 0)

        batch_size = nmt_outputs.shape[1]
        num_sentences += batch_size

        for sent_id in range(batch_size):
            for beam_id in range(num_translations_per_input):
                translation = nmt_utils.get_translation(
                    nmt_outputs[beam_id],
                    sent_id,
                    tgt_eos=tgt_eos,
                    subword_option=subword_option,
                )
    return untokenize_output_string(translation.decode("utf-8"))
```